# How to add onchange to Html.EditorFor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have second thing in my page:

```
<tbody>
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
  {
    ...
    ...

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Option[i].Date, new {id = Model.Option[i].OptionId})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i].Completed, new {id = Model.Option[i].OptionId})
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...
    ...
  }
</tbody>
```

I need to add onchange event for Completed.
I tried to do this in this way:

```
new { id = Model.Option[i].OptionId, onchange = "StateChange()"}
```

and creating function StateChange() **but the problem is** that onchange was not added to my EdditorFor. As a result, no reaction on javascript function at all.

I tried second thing in my BoolYesNo.cshtml (Editor templates):

```
@model bool?

Yes @Html.RadioButton("", true, Model.HasValue && Model.Value == true, htmlAttributes: ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
No @Html.RadioButton("", false, Model.HasValue && Model.Value == false, htmlAttributes: ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

But with no effect.

My question is, how can I actually add onchange event to my @Html.EditorFor? (it is radio ).

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT 1**
@onchange or @onChange are not working.

Comment: You can use new { id= Model.Option[i].OptionId,@onchange = "StateChange();" } You can define StateChange function in javascript to do the required functionality

Comment: I thinked that I already wrote that this didn't work

Comment: You have mentioned onchange. Make it @onchange.

Comment: Well, I will write it again - it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
@onChange = "StateChange()"
```

or alternatively

```
new { id = Model.Option[i].OptionId, @class = "input"}
```

and in the javascript

```
$(".input").on("change", StateChange());
```

Comment: @onChange = "StateChange()" - not working. $("#THEID").on("change", StateChange()) - how I supposed to get my radio id?  As you can see I have a "for" in my example, and as a result radio can have differents Id

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using your code and it worked by setting the onchange like below

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Options[i].Completed, Model.Options[i].OptionId, new { id = Model.Options[i].OptionId.ToString(), Name="radios", @onchange = "StateChange();" })
```